# octave class member variable change not working

Tags: class, octave

I have set up a tiny test class with one member variable. I am trying to change this variable within a member function of the class.

I have named the class: "Test"

I've created a new folder: @Test where all methods are inside. The folder looks like this:
[image]

In Test.m (the constructor) there is the following code:

```
function obj = Test()
  #member variable
  mem.memory = [1,5,2,4,3];  
  obj = class (mem, "Test");
endfunction
```

Then I also have the "display" method:

```
function display(obj)
  obj.memory  
endfunction
```

And the method to change the member variable:

```
function change(obj)
  obj.memory = [9,8,7,8,9];  
endfunction
```

the last thing I have is the main script, here I'm creating a new object of the class Test, display it, change it, display it again. This file lies one folder above the @Test folder:

```
clc
clear all

c = Test();
display(c);
change(c);
display(c);
```

Here is the output of the program:

[image]

Like you can see, the values didn't change to 9 8 7 8 9. It feels like the variable is set to const, but also there comes no error, like: you can not change const variables...

I looked online for some examples, but only could find stange things...
It would be nice, if someone can link me a good tutorial about classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this to

```
function obj = change(obj)
    obj.memory = [9,8,7,8,9];
```

and then call the method as

```
c = change(c);
```

In the MATLAB language, all function inputs are taken by value, not by reference (with the exception of handle classes). Thus, changing the copy of `obj` inside the function does not change the object in the caller workspace. The copy needs to be returned and assigned to the original variable.

MATLAB does optimize the syntax to not actually make any copies. I think Octave does the same, but am not sure.

Comment: @Cris I don't think it optimizes in general, but it does optimize in the specific case of overriding the usual assignment mechanism: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Indexed-Assignment-Optimization.html#Indexed-Assignment-Optimization

Comment: @Tasos: Thanks, that is interesting. This means that in the case of the function `change` above there is no optimization. But on the other hand it doesn’t matter because the whole array is replaced, so it doesn’t need to be copied.